# Hide/show table rows based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some checkboxes which I'd like to use to show/hide rows in a table whose contents match the values of the checkbox which is selected.

Checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='foo1' value='foo1' v-model="selectedType"/> foo1 &nbsp;
<input type='checkbox' name='foo2' value='foo2' v-model="selectedType"/> foo2 &nbsp;
<input type='checkbox' name='bar1' value='bar1' v-model="selectedType"/> bar1 &nbsp;
```

I have an object which I used to construct a table using v-for:

```
<table>
    <template v-for="sampleItem in sampleObj">
        <tr>
           <td>{{sampleItem.item}}</td>
           <td>{{sampleItem.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
</table>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
    data: {
        selectedType: [],
        sampleObj = [{'item': 'item1', 'description': 'foo1 blah'},
                     {'item': 'item2', 'description': 'foo2 vlah'},
                     {'item': 'item3', 'description': 'bar1 nlah'},
                     {'item': 'item4', 'description': 'bar2 clah'},
        ];
    }
});
```

By default, the checkboxes are unchecked. So, only the row which has a cell with description 'bar2' is initially visible. Then when I toggle the other checkboxes, the other rows should also become visible (the descriptions don't match the checkbox values verbatim but has a few words following it. I can do some string processing here).

I thought I could use the v-if directive in the  tag to look at value of selectedType, but I am not sure how I can accomplish this.

Pseudo-code:

```
<tr v-if="selectedType ~= /sampleItem.description/">
...
...
</tr>
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: `v-if="selectedType.find(val => sampleItem.description.indexOf(val) >= 0)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two conditions you need for the `v-if`: if there is no checkbox matching the description, you want the row to display; if there is a checkbox, it has to be checked.

I put the checkbox values into data, where they belong. I made a method for the test. It first looks to see whether the description matches any checkbox value, then it checks whether the matched value is selected.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: [],
    sampleObj: [{
        'item': 'item1',
        'description': 'foo1 blah'
      },
      {
        'item': 'item2',
        'description': 'foo2 vlah'
      },
      {
        'item': 'item3',
        'description': 'bar1 nlah'
      },
      {
        'item': 'item4',
        'description': 'bar2 clah'
      },
    ],
    cbValues: ['foo1', 'foo2', 'bar1']
  },
  methods: {
    isVisible(row) {
      const matchedValue = this.cbValues.find(v => row.description.indexOf(v) >= 0);

      if (!matchedValue) {
        return true;
      }
      return this.selectedType.includes(matchedValue);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="val in cbValues">
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' :value='val' v-model="selectedType"> 
      {{val}}
    </label>
  </div>
  <table>
    <template v-for="sampleItem in sampleObj">
        <tr v-if="isVisible(sampleItem)">
           <td>{{sampleItem.item}}</td>
           <td>{{sampleItem.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I have a question which maybe not related to vuejs - the checkboxes appear one below the other when its populated using `v-for` but next to each other when I don't use it but manually code each of the checkboxes. Would it have something to do with vuejs?

Comment: No, it has to do with the `display` CSS property of the elements. You see I put my `v-for` on a `div`, which has `display:block`. By itself, checkbox has `display: inline`.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. With style `display: inline` applied to the div, checkboxes appears next to each other.