# Correct format for listing array as table rows in vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on this webpage where I want to display table rows based on the checkbox selection. I was able to generate working example using this question:
[Hide/show table rows based on checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574586/hide-show-table-rows-based-on-checkbox)

My problem is I am getting array as response instead of formatted rows. Not sure what am I missing here.

Please check the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4roe2kjq/1/

```html
<html>
<style>

    td {
border: thin solid black;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top: 5px
    }

</style>

<script src="/javascript/vue.js"></script>


 <div id="app">
      <div v-for="val in cbValues">
        <label>
          <input type='checkbox' :value='val' v-model="selectedType"> 
          {{val}}
        </label>
      </div>
      <table>
      
      
        <template v-for="c in staff_member">
    


              <tr v-if="isVisible(c)">
               <td>{{c.courses}}</td>
            </tr>


  
        </template>
        
        </table>

<script>


   new Vue({
      el: '#app',


      data: {

        selectedType: [],
           staff_member:[{
   
      description :'Non-lab Staff Member',
    courses:[
      {course :'first'},
      {course :'second'}

    ]

  }],
  
  
  
        cbValues: [
        'Non-lab Staff Member'
        ]
      },
      methods: {
        isVisible(row) {
           const matchedValue = this.cbValues.find(v => row.description.indexOf(v) >= 0);
          if (!matchedValue) {
            return true;
          }
          return this.selectedType.includes(matchedValue);
        }
      }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: have you tried using `v-for`?

Comment: Your HTML document is malformed. You are missing `<head>` and `<body>`

Comment: @Bravo Yes, not sure what I keep missing here. I have been staring it for hours. I tried ```v-for="c in staff_member```

Comment: `<td v-for="({course}, key) in c.courses" :key="key">{{course}}</td>`

Comment: Do you want to display each course in different rows or in different columns?

Comment: @Giovane Was away from computer. Row is preferred. I see your answer now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could understand, you want to show a table of courses depending on the selection of staff members, right?

You are displaying an array of courses because you aren't iterating the staff's courses array, you are only iterating the staffs and displaying the courses raw value.

A quick refactoring in your code, would look something like this:

```html
...
  <table>
    <template v-for="(staff, key2) in staff_member" :key="key2">
      <template v-if="isVisible(staff)">
        <tr v-for="(course, key3) in staff.courses" :key="key3">
          <td>{{course.course}}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </template>
  </table>
```

Besides iterating over the staffs, you should iterate over the staff's courses.

Something important that you should use is the `key` attribute whenever you use `v-for`, take a look at the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key)

Comment: Here is the updated jsfiddle link with updates from Giovane's answer : https://jsfiddle.net/4roe2kjq/2/